# Django template : display objects in cascade with foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to display some django objects in my template which are connected by `Foreign Key field`.

I tried to make an easy example in order to illustrate what I would like to get in my template with `accordion html`.

***My django model :***

```
class Grandparent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    age = models.IntegerField(...)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} : {self.age}"


class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    age = models.IntegerField(...)
    grandparent = models.ForeignKey(Grandparent, related_name='grandparent')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} : {self.age}"


class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    age = models.IntegerField(...)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='parent')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} : {self.age}"
```

As you can see, child depends from parent which depends from grandparent.

***My html template :***

Now I would like to display something like that in my HTML template :

[image]

So my HTML looks like below and I don't overcome to get what I want :

```
{% for grandparent in grandparent_list %}
<div class="accordion-publication panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="button" id="head_0" data-toggle="collapse">
      <span>{{ grandparent }}</span>
    </div>
    {% for parent in parent_list %}
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true">
            <span class="panel-title">{{ parent }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="head_0">
            <div class="panel-body">
            {% for child in child_list %}
              <table class="table table-condensed">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-1"> {{ child }}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

This HTML is a bit generic, but I don't overcome to get relations between each level and sub-level in order to display `for each grandparent` displays `each parents associated` then displays `each child associated to each parent` ..

***My django view :***

My class in my django view looks like this :

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    self.count_number_document()
    self.flag_publication()
    kwargs['child_list'] = Child.objects.all().order_by('parent__grandparent__name')
    kwargs['parent_list'] = Parent.objects.all().order_by('name')
    kwargs['grandparent_list'] = Grandparent.objects.all()

    return super(MyClassView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Your related names don't make sense. The `related_name` for `Parent.grandparent` is used to get you the related *parents*, therefore it would be better to use `related_name='parents'`. Similarly, it would be better to use `related_name='children` for `Child.parent`.

Comment: @Alasdair OK you're right, but I think that my main issue is about my `get_context_data` method and `for loop` in my template ? On that part I'm blocked for the moment. Even if I will correct my model with your comment.

Comment: @Alasdair I fount the answer ! I will answer to my question and make it at solution. Thank you very much because your comment on `related_name` let me to get an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Alasdair's answer, I found the solution.

Firstly, I have to define my model like this (`related_name` adjustement) :

```
class Grandparent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    age = models.IntegerField(...)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} : {self.age}"


class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    age = models.IntegerField(...)
    grandparent = models.ForeignKey(Grandparent, related_name='parents')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} : {self.age}"


class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    age = models.IntegerField(...)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} : {self.age}"
```

Then, in my view.py file, I just have to set :

```
kwargs['grandparent_list'] = Grandparent.objects.all().order_by('name')
```

And finally in my html template :

```
{% for grandparent in grandparent_list %}
<div class="accordion-publication panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="button" id="head_0" data-toggle="collapse">
      <span>{{ grandparent }}</span>
    </div>
    {% for parent in grandparent.parents.all %}
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true">
            <span class="panel-title">{{ parent }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="head_0">
            <div class="panel-body">
            {% for child in parent.children.all %}
              <table class="table table-condensed">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-1"> {{ child }}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use 'children' on all your the related names so that grandparent.children.all() will give all the children of grand parent ie Parent instances. Similarly for the Parent and Child class as well.

Coming to the view, send only grandparents in the context. But wait, this will lead to N+1 queries if you access the children and their children.
So use prefetch when sending the grandparents.

```
grandparents = Grandparent.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch('children', queryset=Parent.objects.all().prefetch_related('children')))
```